# Problem with no_proxy environment variable, Python and Docker

Tags: python, linux, docker, selenium

I have Python's scraper in Docker container, which is using Scrapy and Selenium (Chrome) and everything works fine until I set the proxy.
I have bash script which runs the Python script and I set something like this:

```bash
export HTTP_PROXY=http://user:password@p.webshare.io:80/
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://user:password@p.webshare.io:80/
export NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1
export no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1

python main.py
```

second variable is aimed to ensure that the settings will be respected.

When I comment out the PROXY variables, it works. But when I run the scraper with proxy settings, the Selenium part doesn't seem to work.
I looked at the log and there's something that probably shows what kind of problem this is.

```
app_1  | 2023-01-16 21:59:47 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://localhost:58683 "POST /session/fb57da8f4b8b938c2ec744eb32cc2ca4/element HTTP/1.1" 404 883
app_1  | 2023-01-16 21:59:47 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Remote response: status=404 | data={"value":{"error":"no such element","message":"no such element: Unable to locate element: {\"method\":\"css selector\",\"selector\":\".mu-product-details-page\"}\n  (Session info: headless chrome=108.0.5359.124)","stacktrace":"#0 0x5574a38762a3 \u003Cunknown>\n#1 0x5574a3634f77 \u003Cunknown>\n#2 0x5574a367180c \u003Cunknown>\n#3 0x5574a3671a71 \u003Cunknown>\n#4 0x5574a36ab734 \u003Cunknown>\n#5 0x5574a3691b5d \u003Cunknown>\n#6 0x5574a36a947c \u003Cunknown>\n#7 0x5574a3691903 \u003Cunknown>\n#8 0x5574a3664ece \u003Cunknown>\n#9 0x5574a3665fde \u003Cunknown>\n#10 0x5574a38c663e \u003Cunknown>\n#11 0x5574a38c9b79 \u003Cunknown>\n#12 0x5574a38ac89e \u003Cunknown>\n#13 0x5574a38caa83 \u003Cunknown>\n#14 0x5574a389f505 \u003Cunknown>\n#15 0x5574a38ebca8 \u003Cunknown>\n#16 0x5574a38ebe36 \u003Cunknown>\n#17 0x5574a3907333 \u003Cunknown>\n#18 0x7f52d0dc4609 start_thread\n"}} | headers=HTTPHeaderDict({'Content-Length': '883', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'cache-control': 'no-cache'})
```

It looks like the Selenium deamon just ignored the NO_PROXY environment variable and tried to connect to the browser via proxy.

I wanted to set NO_PROXY with certain IP's with port number like localhost:58683, but I think that port changes randomly. I wrote some bash code to automatically create list of all localhost adressess from port 8080 up to 65000 but then the bash reported an error that the list is too long.

Does anyone have an idea how could I fix that?

Edit:
[here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/9925) I found the following idea:

> As a stop gap you can instantiate your own RemoteConnection object and have ignore_proxy=True

But I don't know how to create custom RemoteConnection object and 'inject' into Selenium instance.